# codeigniter RESTful API retuning JSON syntax error

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, rest, api

The JSON response from Codeigniter's RESTful API is inserting HTML in front of the JSON, causing the JSON response to die before I can actually get into the JSON. I'm using POSTMAN to test, and it's giving me

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON
```

Here's the raw response:

```
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>

{"status":"success","message":[{"listitem_title":"Religion, Secularism, and Constitutional Democracy (Religion, Culture, and Public Life)","listitem_author":"","listitem_url":"https:\/\/stpsu.on.worldcat.org\/search?queryString=bn:9780231168717","listitem_img":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/41ed54Udo6L.jpg","listitem_id":"328","list_name":"New bookss Aug 29","page_list_id":"50","list_description":"New books for August 29","inst_id":"1"}..........
```

So it is returning something. But it's inserting HTML before... so frustrating...

Here is my controller:

```
    function featuredslideshow_get(){
    //calls the featured slideshow data in JSON format
    $inst_id = $this->uri->segment(3);

    //locate featured pagelist ID
    $inst_data = $this->user_model->get_config($inst_id);

    //set pagelist ID
    $featured_id = $inst_data->featured_pagelist;

    //Find and search for featured items by pagelist ID
    $titles = $this->pagelist_model->pagelist_with_items($featured_id);

    if(isset($titles)){
        $this->response(array('status' => 'success', 'message'=> $titles));
    }else{
        $this->response(array('status' => 'failure', 'message' => 'The specified institution could not be found' ), REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
    }
}//end of featured slideshow
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on how I can get rid of this HTML and just have RAW JSON using this PHP library?? Thanks so much

Comment: try with adding die() function after response in method

Comment: Use  ob_end_clean(); before response

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter--net-8814

Comment: Thanks @user3774708 ob_end_clean(); was able to solve my issue. This was very helpful!